# How to keep canvas position of saved image no matter the device resolution in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am saving three imageviews to one bitmap after the user edits the image(s). The problem is that once the final result is saved, the resulting saved image doesn't always look the same on different screen resolutions.

On my phone, which is a Asus Padfone X, the saved image comes out perfectly. On my partners phone, Note 6, the positioning of the saved images on the resulting bitmap are off. (See example below)

I am using the following code to save the imageviews to a single image:

```
Bitmap mainBmp = backImage.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap centerBmp = centerImage.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap handleBmp = handleImage.getDrawingCache();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBmp);
canvas.drawBitmap(centerBmp, 17, 95, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(handleBmp, 17, 85, null);
```

Which saves properly on my phone but not one with a bigger screen/higher resolution. How do I ensure the resulting saved image looks the same regardless of the device it is saved on?

**EXAMPLE OF DIFFERENCE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale.  For example, lets say that device 1 is 500x1000 pixels and device 2 is 600x1200.  Lets say the bitmap is 300x400 and starts at an offset of 30 pixels in x and 100 in y.

The bitmap needs to grow in size by the ratio of the two screens sizes.  So it would need to be 300*(600/500) pixels wide and 400*(1200/1000) pixels big.  The offset would need to scale as well- to 30*(600/500) and 100*(1200/1000).

Please note that when scaling you may get stretching, pixelation, and other image defects.  The more you stretch the worse it will be.  Shrinking can also give defects, but these tend to be more minor.

This is the simple case-  the two screens I gave have the same aspect ratio (ratio of width:height).  In the case of different aspect ratios, you need to choose:

1)Keep the aspect ratio of the image the same.  This will mean you'll have blank space in 1 direction, but the image won't be effected.

2)Allow the aspect ratio of the image to change.  This will leave no blank space, but will skew the image.

For #2, use the same code as above.  For #1, figure out which dimension needs to scale the least, and use that to scale x and y.

It is not possible to scale from any size phone to any size phone without any defects on a generic image.  You'll have to choose between the two options above.

Comment: Thank you. That was more than informative. I appreciate you taking the time to educate me.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that if I instead use imageview.getWidth() and imageview.getHeight(), I can position each "layer" where I need it to be no matter the screen size. I tested this method on a small android device all the way up to a tablet and the saved image came out perfect across all devices.

What I did was determine the pixel size of each image("layer") using Photoshop. I then used an online px to dp calculator/converter to determine the correct dp size of each layer. I set specific dp width and height for each layer in the layout. For each layer I needed to save to the main image, I calculated the x and y dimensions by taking the mainimageviews height and width and subtracting the pixels needed from the edge to the respective edge of that layer. Through trial and error, I ran the app a few times to get the exact positioning of each layer I wanted. The result of the saved image was exactly the way it looked to the user. Hope this helps someone else in the future.